# Issues pushing to private git repositories in linux

Tags: linux, git, github

Hi I have the following git private repo

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/sescobb27/festinare_api.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/sescobb27/festinare_api.git (push)
ssh git@github.com:sescobb27/festinare_api.git (fetch)
ssh git@github.com:sescobb27/festinare_api.git (push)
```

but when I try to run `git push origin master` it says

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/sescobb27/festinare_api.git/' not found
```

but if instead I run `git push ssh master` it works, I don't know what's going on or why is that happening; the weird thing is that the last week they were working.

I'm on xubuntu xfce 14.04LTS

UPDATE

```
git config --local -l

core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
credential.helper=store
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/sescobb27/festinare_api.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.ssh.url=git@github.com:sescobb27/festinare_api.git
remote.ssh.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/ssh/*
```

Answer (score 0):

An https push should ask for your credentials (github login '`escobb27`', and GitHub password): it should work then.
If it does not ask for credentials, then it might pick some from a [credential helper](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials) which could cache the wrong credentials.
In any case, a private repo with incorrect credentials will always return "`404: not found`".

An ssh push would work directly because the public ssh key which authenticate you has been added to the private repo on GitHub.

I advised in the comments to try, suspecting some error in the `.gitconfig`:

```
git remote set-url origin https://sescobb27@github.com/sescobb27/festinare_api
```

And the OP confirms:

> I already fix it, there was an error in my `.gitconfig` file, once I fixed it git started working as expected, but the error wasn't obvious
>
> I think the error was indentation and mixed tabs with spaces, but I'm not sure. didn't have vim configured to translate tabs to spaces so that makes the mess.

Comment: yes, I'm caching my credentials, and they are ok, if I disable caching in my `.gitconfig` the error still occurs, but right now I'm on a OSX pc and the error still occurs but I'm able to push to other people repos (private and public ones). I'm looking in my github account and it says `Micro – Using 5 of 5 private repositories.` is github blocking my pushes over https because I exhaust my private repos?

Comment: @sescob27 that is very possible, if `festinare_api` is your sixth private repo.

Comment: @sescob27 But at least I wanted to point out why ssh would work. And if it does work, that should mean `festinare_api` is part of the 5 private repos.

Comment: I delete 2 of the private repos, now I only have 3 private repos but the problem remains :(, do you know how to fix it? I need to push over https, because where I study the port 22 for ssh is blocked so I'm not able to push changes

Comment: @sescob27 can you edit your question with a copy of `git config --local -l`? Just to see how *exactly* the url for the remote origin is specified in there.

Comment: @sescob27 could you try: `git remote set-url origin https://sescobb27@github.com/sescobb27/festinare_api`, and then try to push again?

Comment: I already did that without success, but I already fix it, there was an error in my .gitconfig file, once I fixed it git started working as expected, but the error wasn't obvious, thanks for your time :).

Comment: @sescob27 Great. Could you tell me the error, for me to add to the answer for more visibility? (for others to benefit from)

Comment: I think the error was indentation and mixed tabs with spaces, but I'm not sure. didn't have vim configured to translate tabs to spaces so that makes the mess. thanks :)

Comment: @sescob27 Thank you. I have added your conclusion to the answer, for more visibility.